# Scatter plot doesn't chart data points in the correct location

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, scatter-plot

My X values consist of floats. When my data points are charted they are only placed on the integer version of the x axis. For instance 4.4 will be placed directly above the 4 on the x axis instead of between 4 and 5. This leads to a scatter plot with a straight line with data points stacking above one another and not placed correctly.

I was expecting to have each data point correctly placed in relation to the x axis

```
plt.scatter(cdf.CYLINDERS, cdf.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.xlabel("Engine size")
plt.ylabel("Emission")
plt.show()
```

Please view the image for better understandment:

[image]

Comment: can you try updating your pandas/numpy/matplotlib versions if they are outdated

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch All the other scatter charts created are plotted correctly. It's just this one for some odd issue.

Comment: @AdrianDiaz show array data to render.